# How to run a cron queue programmatically?

Tags: hooks, cron, queue

I have created a cron queue like given below.

```
function mymodule_cron_queue_info() {
  $queues['aggregator_feeds'] = array(
    'worker callback' => 'aggregator_refresh',
    'time' => 60,
  );
  return $queues;
}
```

My cron runs when calling drush cron. I need to run the queue 'aggregator_feeds' individually without invoking any other cron queues. Drupal admin panel -> config -> cron : runs all queues as per schedule. 
drush cron command too runs all queue. How do I run a single queue programmatically?

Also I need to know how to run all the queues programmatically?

Answer (score 3):

For one of my project, this worked for me :-

```
$queue_machine_name = 'sync_product_list';
$queue = \Drupal::queue($queue_machine_name); 
$queue_worker = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.queue_worker')->createInstance($queue_machine_name);
$item_id = '123';
$queue_worker->processItem($item_id);
```